# Data warehouse Fact table foreign key Generation

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I am pretty new to data warehouse designing.
I have a database like below.
[image]

https://webpages.charlotte.edu/mirsad/itcs6265/group1/domain.html

I am planning to create a simple data warehouse like below.

[image]

But the problem I am facing now is I don't have ClientId and LoanId in the Fact table. Because in the original database it was lnked via Account table.
I am trying to achieve this via SQL server. Can someone show me the direction how to approach this.

Comment: So you just need to join via the Account table to get the IDs that you need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the FactTransaction fact table you don't need the Loan because it represents a fact so Transaction and Loan are two differnt actions like mentioned in the data dictionary :

> TRANSACTIONS (TRANS) Each record describes one transaction on an
> account
>
> LOANS Each record describes a loan granted for a given account

the design can be like below if we follow a separate context for each :

**Datamart Transaction :**

[image]

**Datamart Loan :**

[image]

The query to populate the FactTransaction is like below :

```
SELECT T.account_id AS TransactionID, C.client_id AS ClientID,
A.account_id AS AccountID
FROM Transactions AS T
LEFT JOIN Account AS A ON A.account_id=T.account_id
LEFT JOIN Disposition AS D ON A.account_id=D.account_id
LEFT JOIN Client AS C ON C.client_id=D.client_id
```

AccountID, TransactionID, ClientID represent a composite key to uniquely identify the tuple transaction in a the fact table.

The query to populate the FactLoan is like below :

```
 SELECT L.account_id AS LoanID, C.client_id AS ClientID,
A.account_id AS AccountID
    FROM Loan AS L
    LEFT JOIN Account AS A ON A.account_id=A.account_id
    LEFT JOIN Disposition AS D ON A.account_id=D.account_id
    LEFT JOIN Client AS C ON C.client_id=D.client_id
```

AccountID, LoanID, ClientID represent a composite key to uniquely identify the tuple transaction in a the fact table.

Do not forget to implement the DimDate.

Comment: Amira: how have you concluded that the transactions don’t apply to loans and therefore there is no need for a Loans Dim? You seem to have made some unsupported assumptions about the question and then spent a lot of effort answering a question that wasn’t asked

Comment: @NickW I checked the link that he provided and tried to understand the business requirements.